# What dose zero_debias mean in tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage?

Tags: tensorflow

tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage has a parameter 'zero_debias', but I don't know what will happen if I set it to True. So what's this parameter for?

Great thanks in advance.